# ulimit unlimited cannot set

Tags: ulimit

I'm having a problem setting ulimits to unlimited.
I am a member of the @audio group
Here are the contents of my /etc/security/limits.conf

> @audio   -  rtprio     95
>
> @audio   -  memlock    unlimited

I know audio group is working because I have realtime settings working.

Here is the output of the ulimits -l -r

```
$ ulimit -r -l
real-time priority              (-r) 95
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
```

So the realtime is working but the max locked memory is not working.
Not sure what got messed up.  I don't want to reinstall to make this work Using ubuntu 19.04

I have jack installed too.  Maybe this is messing things up.
There are two files in the limits.d folder that I created.. but now deleted.

Comment: Did you check from new (open AFTER you save the file) terminal after you edit `limits.conf` file?

Comment: I ended up doing a reinstall. I have not installed jack or ardour.  still have the problem.  Yes.. the file is set as described (after booting)... it is there.

Comment: I think it is a bug in 19.04.  I opted to install Mate which always works.. and it did.  I did nothing different.  Both were fresh installs. Not sure how to write a bug post since I no longer have ubuntu.

Comment: "a new terminal" would not be sufficient to test configuration changes made via PAM configuration files. Those changes require a fresh login through whatever service is reading the configuration files in question -- eg a new ssh login, or new gdm login, or new getty login, depending upon your local PAM configuration.

Comment: I had no problems with mate

Comment: Same problem, Ubuntu 19.04. Put `session required pam_limits.so` in `/etc/pam.d/common-session` as well as in `runuser` (added also almost everywhere else as a desperate attempt to solve); tried to add in `/security/limits.conf` a redundant `@audio - memlock unlimited` and my user is in the group audio (redundant because that's in `limits.d/audio.conf` altogether with `@audio - rtprio 95`, which is honored, a configuration from jackd package). This is really annoying since 1. it used to work 2. fluidsynth, among others, won't do its job.

Comment: and I also messed up with `systemd` according to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1837580), but nothing solved the issue so far.

Answer (score 0):

Hour wasted - but, here's what worked on Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon:
include these 4 lines in limit.conf:

```
@audio          hard    rtprio          95
@audio          soft    rtprio          95
@audio          hard    memlock     unlimited
@audio          soft    memlock     unlimited
```

Hawkeye posted this info about another issue here:
[Original hint](https://serverfault.com/questions/359185/limits-conf-not-being-applied)
Thanks to him!